# How to make an HTTP request from a plugin?

Tags: guzzle, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to be able to make HTTP requests from within my plugin to hit an endpoint and get a response. How can I do this?

Comment: Something tells me you already knew the answer to this! ;)

Answer (score 9):

Craft uses an HTTP library called Guzzle, and it's built-in so you can import and use it from within your plugin. Here's an example:

```
// imports
use GuzzleHttp;

// GET request

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com', [
  'query' => ['exampleParam' => 'example']
]);
$responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

// POST request
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://example.com/api', [
  'form_params' => [
    'example' => 'example',
  ]
]);
$responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

To figure out how to properly format your Guzzle request, refer to the [Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).